# Limit of a bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

The $\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{\sin(n)+7}{15})^{n^2}=0$.
This is due by the fact that $|a_n|=|\frac{\sin(n)+7}{15}|<1$?

Comment: In fact, $|a_n| \le 3/4$.

Comment: $|a_n|<1$ is not sufficient to conclude that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n^n$ because you could have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n=1$. For instance, take $a_n=1-\frac{1}{n}$, then $|a_n|<1$ for all $n$ but $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n^n=\frac{1}{e}$.

Comment: You can find $k<1$ such that $|a_n|\leqslant k$ for all $n$, thus you can't have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

we know that

$-1\leq \sin n \leq 1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{4} \leq\frac{2+\sin n}{4} \leq \frac{3}{4}$

which means

$(\frac{1}{4})^n \leq (\frac{2+\sin n}{4})^n \leq ( \frac{3}{4})^n$ and

$lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{1}{4})^n=lim_{n \to \infty}( \frac{3}{4})^n=0$ according to sandwich theorem

$lim_{n \to \infty}(\frac{2+\sin n}{4})^n=0 $

Comment: it is due to a more general fact that $a,b,c,d \geq 0: a<b$ and $c<d \Rightarrow ac<bd$

Answer (score 0):

We can use the triangle inequality
$$0 \le \left|\frac{\sin(n)+7}{15}\right|^{n^2} \le \left(\left|\frac{\sin(n)}{15}\right| + \frac{7}{15}\right)^{n^2} \le \left(\frac 12\right)^{n^2}$$
Therefore $a_n \to 0, \text{ as } n \to \infty$.

BTW you changed your sequence?